# Errors showing in powershell, solution cannot be found

Tags: python, powershell, numpy

This is showing that it's not an error of pip but I couldn't yet find out the solution for this particular error, wheel and setup packages are installed and up to date, python version is also latest but still after multiple tries and attempts of overcoming the error something like this is showing up. There was another error before installing wheels but now that I installed wheel, that has been overcome automatically.

```
pip :   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install numpy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (  error: subprocess-exited-with-error:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [33 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in 
get_requires_for_build_wheel
      backend = _build_backend()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
      obj = import_module(mod_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1293, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1266, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1216, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 400, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1293, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1266, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1237, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 841, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 400, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qlb37fm5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      import setuptools.version
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qlb37fm5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pkg_resources
    File "C:\Users\akars\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qlb37fm5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
      register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried multitple similar answers for similar errors but nothing works for this. Powershell is also showing errors for other packages as well.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?`

The error message says that the [`pkgutil.ImpImporter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.ImpImporter) attribute is missing. The docs say that this attribute is deprecated since Python version 3.3. I do not really know how to fix this, but maybe it helps to update `setuptools`(`python -m pip --upgrade setuptools`).

Answer (score 6):

This from [this blog post](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/10/fix-broken-pip-python-312-ubuntu/) worked for me!

Python has a built-in module ensurepip, to provide support for bootstrapping the pip installer into an existing Python installation.

```
python3.12 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same kind of error upgrading a Poetry environment from Python 3.11 -> 3.12, and Pillow from 9.x -> 10.x. In my case, `pip` was already installed, but needed to upgrade from 23.0.1 to 23.2.1 for the new version of Pillow to install successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to the latest Python 3.12 release.

I had the same problem, but once I changed my Dockerfile's Python version to 3.11, it worked.

I would suggest changing the Python runtime environment to 3.11 or 3.9, as they are considered secure and stable releases.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem occurs for two reasons

1. python 3.12 was missing from the `PATH`
2. I had an old version of `PyCharm` installed

For Windows users the following steps worked for me:

- press `Win + R`
- Run the command `sysdm.cpl`
- `Advanced`
- `Environment Variables`
- `Edit System Environment Variables`
- select `Path` and then click edit
- add the path that you installed python 3.12. Should look like this: `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\`
- Move the variable up to be first
- Update `PyCharm`

**Delete the existing virtual environment and create a new one for your project.**